# How to keep user logged in for one month in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I have searched all through StackOverflow and other forums, and have not found a way to make my code work. I have a basic login mechanism setup for my users, and it works just fine. However, when a browser is closed the user must visit the site and log back in. I need to find a way to keep the user logged in for a period of one month.

I researched cookies and experimented for two days, but consistently when I exit out of the browser and load the site back up, the user is logged out. The only thing that sort of worked was using ini_set to change the session.gc_maxlifetime and session.lifetime variables, but for some odd reason no matter what values I assigned to those two variables the user would only stay logged in for around 4 hours. So, does anyone know if I am doing something wrong in setting the cookie below, or how I can fix my problem? Thank you in advance for your answers, I am at my wits end with this issue.

```
        //create cookie, set expiration to one month (in seconds)

        setcookie("user",$username,time()+2592000);
        echo $_COOKIE["user"];

        session_start();

        //Login Successful, begin session

        $member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        $_SESSION['table'] = $table;

        session_write_close();

        //header("location: search.php");
        exit();
```

Comment: Since cookies exist on the client there's no real way to enforce this; even if you set the cookie to expire in a year the user can still just delete it.

Comment: Echoing the `$_COOKIE` variable after doing `setcookie`, will not contain what you just set it too. First call, it will be empty. Second call, it will be what it was when it came into the script. If you wish to change and use the new value in `$_COOKIE` you need to also assign the new value to it when you use `setcookie` ... `$_COOKIE['user'] = 'newval';`

Comment: Why is the password being stored in the session, and why call it `last_name`?

Comment: This code is so partial, its difficult to tell what exactly is being done. From the sounds of it, you are fighting session cookies vs persistent cookies, and as CD001 said... a user can always delete their cookies (or even reject them firsthand).

Comment: @IncredibleHat - since my browsers are always configured to delete all cookies on shutdown, as far as I'm concerned persistent cookies don't exist ;)

Comment: @CD001 heh, well, yeah there is that too. Whenever an admin complains about having to login everyday, we just tell them to allow the security token cookies, or shutupaboutit :D

Comment: Are you're storing session data in the default location? That means that any other app can remove your sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In loggin page add (sessions):

```
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

and index check:

```
session_start();

$timeout = 7200; //time in seconds

if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    $duracao = time() - (int) $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($duracao > $timeout) {
      session_start();
      session_destroy();
      session_unset();
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.href='index.php'</script>";
    }
}
```